# file_get_contents, HTTP request failed

Tags: php, httprequest, file-get-contents

I try to get content from another site by using `file_get_contents` but I always get "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!" allow_url_fopen is on, and I have tested with my firewall off. But it still happens, what other reasons can it be?

EDIT:
Here is the full message
Warning: file_get_contents(http://yemto.deviantart.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in D:\xampp\htdocs\deviantart\webcam\img.php on line 15

And code

```
//Load the page into a DOMDocument
$file = file_get_contents(strToLower("http://".$user.".deviantart.com/"));//TO-DO <-- if deivantart name is empty, it crashes
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc -> loadHTML($file);
```

Comment: Can you add the URL you're trying to call to the post, please? :)

Comment: added, with a little piece of the code too.

Comment: Very weird, I'm getting the same error when I try to get your page with `file_get_contents`, but it works from the web browser on the same machine, and also using `curl` in the shell.

Comment: Try using curl from php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your webserver closes the connection immediately if the client doesn't send a `User-Agent` header. Try adding a `user_agent` option to your `php.ini`, or put:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP');
```

in your script.