# Issue with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am writing a code in PHP which fetches the content in a particular format from around 20 websites.

It is working normally for all the websites except one. Now, here is the issue.
I am using `file_get_contents()` to fetch images from the website and save it on my server. The image is present on the remote server and is accessible via browser but I am getting 404 response while doing it via code.

I am unable to understand the issue behind this as this method works perfectly for other websites.

Has it something to do with the headers being sent? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe that one website has an htaccess/apache rule to prevent image hotlinking. I.e. if the referer is not their site, it won't load.

Comment: @akshitsethi: Can you post the exact code that is being used? Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Maybe it's similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314753/file-get-contents-http-request-failed/22314941#22314941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is probably: yes...

They're checking user-agents, I suppose.

And those are sent in your headers. You can fake your user-agent. Don't use `file_get_contents()` though, as that one doens't allow faking your user-agent.
Look into [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

**Edit 1**

Barmar's link shows a possibility to use `file_get_contents()` with a different user-agent at the same time. It's worth while looking into...

**Edit 2**

But it could also be about then checking the **referrer**... If that is the case you really need to use `curl` to be able to set the **referrer**.

**Edit 3**

Having seen the URL now, and looking at error `404` that you get (not a `50x`) , I advise you to check if the URL is being escaped and parsed ok. I see that the URL contains spaces, and two slashes after the domain name. Check if spaces are escaped into %20 and if the double slashed shouldn't be stripped to just one slash.

So

```
http://celebslam.celebuzz.com//bfm_gallery/2014/03/Lindsay Lohan 2 Broke Girls/gallery_enlarged/gallery_enlarged-lindsay-lohan-2-broke-girls-01.jpg
```

Should become

```
http://celebslam.celebuzz.com/bfm_gallery/2014/03/Lindsay%20Lohan%202%20Broke%20Girls/gallery_enlarged/gallery_enlarged-lindsay-lohan-2-broke-girls-01.jpg
```

And notice, the server is CaSe-SeNsItIvE !

Comment: Even I thought that they must be checking user-agents. How can I send something that the website might accept? Something that they believe that the request came from their own website.

Comment: You say if you use your own browser to get the file directly, you succeed. Or do you mean you use the browser to visit the site and get the image afterwards? Because then it's not about user-agent, but about REFERRER... (also a user-agent thingy... If that's the case, you really need to use curl, to be able to set the REFERRER)

Comment: I am able to open the image directly. So, it means REFERRER is not where the problem lies. What do you think? The photo I am trying to fetch is http://celebslam.celebuzz.com//bfm_gallery/2014/03/Lindsay%20Lohan%202%20Broke%20Girls/gallery_enlarged/gallery_enlarged-lindsay-lohan-2-broke-girls-01.jpg

Comment: That image works fine for me using file_get_contents. Are you sleeping between fetches (it could be ddos protection).

Comment: @akshitsethi : then it is very probable the user-agent as said before... But also check what Aziz is saying...

Comment: @akshitsethi and read my 3rd edit in my answer about double slashes and spaces and case sensitivity.

Comment: @nl-x Thanks for pointing out. It works! How can I be soo stupid :( I was not encoding the URL.. Thank you once again.

Comment: @AzizSaleh Thank you for your help mate. It was a silly mistake from my end.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, first of all - check, if that site check referrer on images access. For example try to get image directly in browser

It also can check user-agent field and something else

Probably it will help to get file by curl ( code examples easy to find or i'll give you simple class )

P.S> just interesting. Can you give some images url examples to try?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the referral or user agent. This includes both:

```
function file_get_contents_custom($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux; i686; en-US; rv:1.6) Gecko Debian/1.6-7'); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Update:

The image you linked works fine for me using file_get_contents. It might be that the server has some sort of DDOS protection. How many requests are you making a second on average?