# PHP: file_get_contents and curl are not working for some sites

Tags: php, curl

I want to fetch some contents of site, so I am using file_get_contents or curl function in php. But the problem is that these functions are not working for every site, eg: they are working for google.com, but not working for iteye.com. my code likes below:

```
$baseurl = 'http://www.iteye.com/';  
$contents = file_get_contents($baseurl);

//OR
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$list = curl_exec($ch);
```

I guess this site blocked the functions (file_get_contents or curl), so how can I continue fetch contents from these sites like iteye.com ?

Comment: You may need to "spoof" the user agent by including: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

Comment: See this question, it might be the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314753/file-get-contents-http-request-failed/22314941#22314941

Comment: www.iteye.com works fine for me.

Comment: 1. curl_setopt is not working...   2. ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP'); is not working.  3. could you try http://justcoding.iteye.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to fetch any site, I would recommend you to use CURL

You must pay attention to:

1. http redirects e.g. 301, 302
2. user agent
3. https
4. sometimes referrer also can be issue

You must behave as much as possible like a human being.

Therefore these directives may not missing in your code also:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to instruct curl to follow redirects, and also to change the user agent:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

$list = curl_exec($ch);
```